# How to determine if Facebook user has changed using PFUser object

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, facebook-login, pfuser

I'm using Parse to handle my login via Facebook. When a user logs in, their Facebook is associated with the PFUser object. However, if a user exits the app, logs out of Facebook and into Facebook with a different account, and then reopens the app, what's the best way to check if the Facebook user has changed?

`[PFUser currentUser]` gets the logged in user from disk, so this won't have changed...

Comment: I believe to find out if the user login in the FB app/website/iOS native FB stuff has changed you'll need to run the login flow again. I was thinking that you could run a graph query (e.g., for `me`) but this would succeed unless the user has changed their FB password or revoked permission for the app, as the app stores the OAuth tokens.

Comment: I suppose I could run a graph query for 'me', and compare the current name with the previous... Shouldn't matter then that the permission token is still active, as the names won't match.

Comment: Sadly, I think (don't know, and would love to be proven wrong!) the names will still match because the authentication for the "me" graph request would be based off the stored OAuth tokens in Parse, and these are for the previously logged in user and your app. OAuth tokens for your app _should_ be independent from the login on the device for the user in the FB app.  It's precisely this property of the tokens that lets you move them around devices and servers and still appear authenticated as that user.

Comment: Yeah you're right - I just tried it. Darn... but there must be a way otherwise this surely represents a rather large security flaw with apps that use Facebook login?

Comment: Probably getting off topic, but I don't see it as a security flaw. It's the same with any service that uses OAuth, or stored credentials in general. If you log out of gmail on your phone in the webUI, would you expect Mail.app to stop receiving email? Or changing twitter accounts in Safari stops tweetbot working? Maybe Facebook is a special case as users may expect logging out to detatch apps, but pretty much nothing else works like this.

Comment: Yes I suppose you're right. I suppose I was more worried about users switching on the same device and the implication that has for my game. But it's not exactly a security issue.